# how to exclude a character once

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to exclude a character once (and everything after):
here is some example

- val=aabbcc,val2==aabb,val3=aa==bb, val4=a=bccc

the pattern is: (any character except =) = (any character)
,here is the result that I wanted :

- val='aabbcc',val2='=aabb',val3='aa==bb', val4='a=bccc'

I tried : ([^=]+)=([^=]+)
and ([^=]+)=(.*)
but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
([^,=]+)=(.*?)(?=,[^,=]+=|$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3Tr9Ad/2).

*Details*:

- `([^,=]+)` - Group 1: one or  more chars other than comma and `=`
- `=` -  `=` char
- `(.*?)` - Group 2: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `(?=,[^,=]+=|$)` - a location that is either immediately followed with  a comma and then zero or more chars other than `,` and `=` and then a `=` char, or end of string.

If you need to get rid of leading/trailing whitespaces, you may use this more complex pattern:

```
([^\s,=](?:[^,=]*[^,=\s])?)\s*=\s*(\S.*?)?\s*(?=,[^,=]+=|$)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3Tr9Ad/4).

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/IhsDyj):

```py
import re
text = "val=aabbcc,val2==aabb,val3=aa==bb, val4=a=bccc"
result = re.findall(r'([^\s,=](?:[^,=]*[^,=\s])?)\s*=\s*(\S.*?)?\s*(?=,[^,=]+=|$)', text)
print(dict(result))
```

Output:

```
{'val': 'aabbcc', 'val2': '=aabb', 'val3': 'aa==bb', 'val4': 'a=bccc'}
```

Comment: please use a complete code, in which the piece of code can be applied

Comment: @FatemehSangin I can't answer quicker than you type your comment. Now, the answer is complete.